# Box plots in Python using Seaborn - creating duplicates for bigrams and trigrams

Tags: python, seaborn, boxplot, cross-validation, text-classification

I am using Spyder as part of Anaconda and trying to classify tweets (text) by event type. To do this, I am using the package *cross_val_score*, having already vectorised my tweets using *TfidVectorizer* and then transforming my training data using *fit_transform* for unigrams, bigrams and trigrams, as per the below:

```
# TF-IDF on unigrams, bigrams and trigrams
tfidf_words = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, min_df=0, norm='l2', encoding='latin-1',
                              ngram_range=(1,1), stop_words='english')

# vectorize for bigrams
tfidf_bigrams = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, min_df=0, norm='l2', encoding='latin-1',
                              ngram_range=(2,2), stop_words='english')

# vecorize for trigrams
tfidf_trigrams = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, min_df=0, norm='l2', encoding='latin-1',
                              ngram_range=(3,3), stop_words='english')

# Transform and fit each of the outputs from TF-IDF (unigrams, bigrams and trigrams)
x_train_words = tfidf_words.fit_transform(x_train_sm.preprocessed).toarray()

# bigrams
x_train_bigrams = tfidf_bigrams.fit_transform(x_train_sm.preprocessed).toarray()

#trigrams
x_train_trigrams = tfidf_trigrams.fit_transform(x_train_sm.preprocessed).toarray()
```

Now I perform cross validation using the package *cross_val_score* to calculate the average accuracy for unigrams, bigrams and trigrams. Once complete, I am trying to produce and save a boxplot for the accuracies achieved. This is completed for 4 different models:

```
# Create list of models to be tested: Random Forest, Linear SVC, Naive Bayes & Logistic Regression

models = [OneVsRestClassifier(RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 200, max_depth=3, random_state=0)), 
          OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC()), OneVsRestClassifier(MultinomialNB()), 
                              OneVsRestClassifier(LogisticRegression(random_state=0))]

# number of folds (10-fold cross validation performed for each model)
CV = 10

########## Fitting, predicting and calculating average accuracy for unigrams data ##########

# create blank dataframe with an index equal to the number of CV folds * number of models tested
cv_words = pd.DataFrame(index=range(CV * len(models)))

#create an empty list, which will be populated with the accuracies of each model at each fold
entries = []

# list of the names of the models tested
names = ["Random Forest", "Linear SVC", "Naive Bayes", "Logistic Regression"]

# convert y_train_sm from an array into a series to work in the 'cross_val_score' function
# this series contains all of the event_ids for the corresponding encoded tweets (labels)
# cross_val_score is a functin used to calculate performance scores and implement cross-validation
y_train_sm = pd.Series(y_train_sm.tolist())

### Fitting, predicting and calculating average accuracy for unigrams data ###

# calculate the accuracy at each fold and populate the results in the 'entries' list
# populate the dataframe 'cv_words' with the fold and accuracy scores at each fold
i = 0
for model in models:
    #model_name = #model.__class__.__name__
    model_name = names[i]
    # model => the model that will be used to fit the data
    # x_train_words_sm => x training data after oversampling (unigrams)
    # y_train_sm => y training data after oversampling (event_id)
    # scoring => the type of score you want the function 'cross_val_score' to return
    # cv = number of folds you want to be performed with cross-validation
    accuracies = cross_val_score(model, x_train_words, y_train_sm, scoring ='accuracy', cv=CV)
    for fold_idx, accuracy in enumerate(accuracies):
        entries.append((model_name, fold_idx, accuracy))
        cv_words = pd.DataFrame(entries, columns=['model_name_unigrams', 'fold_idx', 'accuracy'])
    i = i + 1

# plot the results of each model on a single box plot    
box_words = sns.boxplot(x='model_name_unigrams', y='accuracy', data=cv_words)
fig_words = box_words.get_figure()
fig_words.savefig('boxplot_unigrams.png')
```

The output of the unigrams is exactly what I want:

[image: Boxplot for unigrams]

Now when I run the code for bigrams and trigrams (highlight ALL code and hit 'play'), I get the following:

Bigrams:

[[image: Boxplot for bigrams[2]]

Trigrams:

[image: Boxplot for trigrams]

The code for each of these is identical, except they use 'cv_bigrams' and 'cv_trigrams' for the data input for the box plots. Code for each is below.

Bigram code:

```
# create blank dataframe with an index equal to the number of CV folds * number of models tested
cv_bigrams = pd.DataFrame(index=range(CV * len(models)))

# clear the previous list called 'entries' that was populated with values
entries = []

# calculate the accuracy at each fold and populate the results in the 'entries' list
# populate the dataframe 'cv_bigrams' with the fold and accuracy score at each fold
i = 0
for model in models:
    #model_name = #model.__class__.__name__
    model_name = names[i]
    # model => the model that will be used to fit the data
    # x_train_bigrams_sm => x training data after oversampling (bigrams)
    # y_train_sm => y training data after oversampling (event_id)
    # scoring => the type of score you want the function 'cross_val_score' to return
    # cv = number of folds you want to performed with cross-validation
    accuracies = cross_val_score(model, x_train_bigrams, y_train_sm, scoring ='accuracy', cv=CV)
    for fold_idx, accuracy in enumerate(accuracies):
        entries.append((model_name, fold_idx, accuracy))
        cv_bigrams = pd.DataFrame(entries, columns=['model_name_bigrams', 'fold_idx', 'accuracy'])
    i = i + 1
```

Trigrams code:

```
# create blank dataframe with an index equal to number of CV folds * number of models tested
cv_trigrams = pd.DataFrame(index=range(CV * len(models)))

# clear the previous list called 'entries' that was populated with values
entries = []

# calculate the accuracy at each fold and populate the results in the 'entries' list
# populate the dataframe 'cv_trigrams' with the fold and accuracy score at each fold
i = 0
for model in models:
    #model_name = #model.__class__.__name__
    model_name = names[i]
    # model => the model that will be used to fit the data
    # x_train_trigrams => data that is to be fitted by the selected model (trigrams)
    # y_train_sm => y training data after oversampling (event_id)
    # scoring => the type of score you want the function 'cross_val_score' to return
    # cv = number of folds you want to performed with cross-validation
    accuracies = cross_val_score(model, x_train_trigrams, y_train_sm, scoring ='accuracy', cv=CV)
    for fold_idx, accuracy in enumerate(accuracies):
        entries.append((model_name, fold_idx, accuracy))
        cv_trigrams = pd.DataFrame(entries, columns=['model_name_trigrams', 'fold_idx', 'accuracy'])
    i = i + 1
```

Here is what happens if I select the below code only and run:

```
# plot the results of each model as a box plot    
box_bigrams = sns.boxplot(x='model_name_bigrams', y='accuracy', data=cv_bigrams)
box_bigrams = sns.boxplot(x='model_name_bigrams', y='accuracy', data=cv_bigrams)
fig_bigrams = box_bigrams.get_figure()
fig_bigrams.savefig('boxplot_bigrams.png')
```

[image: Boxplot of bigrams when run on its own]

Same for trigrams:

```
# plot the results of each model as a box plot    
box_trigrams = sns.boxplot(x='model_name_trigrams', y='accuracy', data=cv_trigrams)
box_trigrams = sns.boxplot(x='model_name_trigrams', y='accuracy', data=cv_trigrams)
fig_trigrams = box_trigrams.get_figure()
fig_trigrams.savefig('boxplot_trigrams.png')
```

Output:

[image: Output for trigrams when run on its own]

Any idea why I am getting duplicate boxplots overlapping each other when I run all of the code at once (which I need to do when I put this code into production), rather than highlighting the snippets and running separately?

Comment: The code is much too complicated to see through, but if the aim is to produce each plot in its own figure, add `plt.figure()` before plotting anything in each of the case.

Comment: The problem is that I need to run this code on AWS and not look at each plot. Just run it on a huge dataset and be able to use the exports that are saved.

All the code is doing is calculating the accuracy for 4 different models for 3 different datasets - unigrams, bigrams and trigrams.

I just can't work out why there are duplicates when I run the code as one large block, whereas it's exactly what I want if I run the code by selecting it in stages.

Answer (score 0):

Echoing @ImportanceOfBeingErnest's comment, your code is too complex and your question is not clear enough. Are you trying to create 3 different figures, one for each case (unigram, bigram and trigram)? Are you trying to have one figure with 3 axes (called subplots in matplotlib)? Are you trying to have one graph with the three case side by side?

To me, the simplest would be to create one figure with 3 subplots, like so:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3,1, figsize=(xx,yy))  # choose appropriate size to fit your needs
sns.boxplot(x='model_name_unigrams', y='accuracy', data=cv_unigrams, ax=ax1)
sns.boxplot(x='model_name_bigrams', y='accuracy', data=cv_bigrams, ax=ax2)
sns.boxplot(x='model_name_trigrams', y='accuracy', data=cv_trigrams, ax=ax3)
fig.savefig('your_figure_name_here.png')
```

See the [subplots demo here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html) and documentation about [`plt.subplots()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) or [`fig.add_subplot()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_subplot). In [the documentation for `seaborn.boxplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html?highlight=boxplot#seaborn.boxplot), you'll see that it is an "Axes level" function, meaning you can ask it to plot on whatever Axes object you choose